# Tests fail when scope changes/digests occur in different test blocks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js

I'm "restoring" some directive tests for an AngularJS 1.6.x project. They were added originally years ago, rarely touched, eventually removed, but now I'm putting them back and cleaning things up.

I've noticed that some tests share a `scope` between `it` functions. This used to work, but it no longer does. While I don't *want* to share scope anymore, I have  to better understand the problem before I move on.

In the below test, I bind a `scope.test` value to a letter. This works. I update the property and `$digest` in the next test, yet it fails:

`AssertionError: expected 'a' to equal 'b'`

But what confuses me is that the *exact* same tests work fine/pass when performed with the **same `it` test**.

Why?

- The `scope` object isn't touched/reset between tests
- The `scope.test` value is truly `b`
- The template hasn't been recompiled by accident
- `it` methods should be executed in order

The full self-contained test example:

```
describe('test', () => {
    let scope;
    let $compile;
    let $rootScope;
    let $template;

    // Compile helper
    const compileTemplate = (scope, template) => {
        const $elem = $compile(angular.element(template))(scope);
        scope.$digest();

        return $elem;
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        inject((_$compile_, _$rootScope_) => {
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_
        });
    });

    it('test 1', () => {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.test = 'a';

        $template = compileTemplate(scope, '<div>{{ test }}</div>');

        expect($template.text()).to.equal('a'); // passes
    });

    it('test 2', () => {
        scope.test = 'b';
        scope.$digest();

        expect($template.text()).to.equal('b'); // fails
        // AssertionError: expected 'a' to equal 'b'
    });

    // this does test 1 and 2 all together
    it('test 3', () => {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        scope.test = 'a';
        $template = compileTemplate(scope, '<div>{{ test }}</div>');
        expect($template.text()).to.equal('a'); // passes

        scope.test = 'b';
        scope.$digest();
        expect($template.text()).to.equal('b'); // passes
    });
});
```

Comment: I have a non-answer for you, so I'll leave a comment in case some angular guru cares to get into details.  I ran your code and saw the same behavior you did.  Did some debugging and came to the conclusion that it's not a hill worth dying on, especially since you say yourself you'd rather not share scope across tests.  I suspect the issue comes from the injector in the beforeEach.  Having dependent tests is bad practice, and let's say you wanted to move the injector to beforeAll, angular just says 'nope': https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10238#issuecomment-64868341

Comment: If I had to have an intimate knowledge of each problem I face as a programmer I'd get maybe 10% the amount of work done that I do.  Move on bud and refactor your tests so that they're independent like your gut says :D

Comment: I get it but I prefer to know because nine times out of ten "I don't know" isn't an acceptable justification for work and as a senior dev.

Comment: `beforeEach` did replace `$rootScope` before each tests, therefore it is like you create a distinct realm for test 1 and 2, where local `scope` variable refers to different parent `$rootScope` instances. I render a template again for different test suites. did thought why till this moment:)

Comment: I admire your quest for knowledge, I'll check back to see if you find the root cause.  Word of caution though, I made senior dev by getting things done, not necessarily having an intimate knowledge of all things.  Knowledge of the inner workings of angular.js 1.6 internal mocks api probably wont count for much going forward when their public api says make each test independent.  That said I was sad I couldn't figure this one out lol

Comment: Thanks, I already am a senior dev and not questing, I just want to have answers if at all possible because "I don't know" is too common a reason junior develops just band-aid and problem and move on. I get this gets way more into the weeds than usual but it feels someone with more angular/mocks knowledge could figure it out